# Describe on Dataframe is not displaying the complete resultset

Tags: apache-spark

I am using Scala 1.6.  The describe on a data frame is not displaying the column header and the values.  Please see below:

```
val data=sc.textFile("/tmp/sample.txt")
data.toDF.describe().show
```

This gives the below result:

Please let me know why it is not displaying the entire result set.
    +-------+
    |summary|
    +-------+
    |  count|
    |   mean|
    | stddev|
    |    min|
    |    max|
    +-------+

Comment: Sorry, I meant Spark 1.6 (not Scala 1.6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was because, spark 1.6 was considering every filed as String by default and it does not provide summary stats on String type.  However, in Spark 2.1, the columns were correctly inferred as their respective data type (Int/String/Double etc.,) and summary stats included all the columns in the file and it was not restricted only to numerical fields.

I feel, df.describe() works more elegantly in Spark 2.1 than Spark 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to use the `show` method.

```
sc.textFile("/tmp/sample.txt").toDF.show
```

As far as displaying the complete RDD, be careful with this as you will need to collect the results on the driver in order to do this. You may want to consider using take instead if the csv file is large.

```
val data = sc.textFile("/tmp/sample.txt").toDF
data.collect.foreach(println)
```

or

```
data.take(100).foreach(println)
```

Comment: I want to know about the Describe method.  toDF.describe().show is not displaying the column name or values.  I just get sum, count, min, max, stddev.